# Google Pub/Sub - No event data found from local function after published message to topic

Tags: python-3.x, google-cloud-pubsub, functions-framework, google-cloud-pubsub-emulator

I'm using the [Functions Framework with Python](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/functions-framework-python) alongside [Google Cloud Pub/Sub Emulator](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/emulator). I'm having issues with an event triggered from a published message to a topic, where there's no event data found for the function. See more details below.

- Start Pub/Sub Emulator under `http://localhost:8085` and project_id is `local-test`.
- Spin up function with signature-type: `http` under `http://localhost:8006`.
- Given a background cloud function with signature-type: `event`:

1. [Topic is created](https://github.com/googleapis/python-pubsub/blob/master/samples/snippets/publisher.py#L43) as `test-topic`
2. Function is spinned up under `http://localhost:8007`.
3. [Create push subscription](https://github.com/googleapis/python-pubsub/blob/master/samples/snippets/subscriber.py#L145) `test-subscription` for `test-topic` for endpoint: `http://localhost:8007`

When I publish a message to `test-topic` from `http://localhost:8006` via POST request in Postman, I get back a 200 response to confirm the message was published successfully. The function representing `http://localhost:8007` gets executed as an `event` as shown in the logs from the functions-framework. However, there's no actual data for `event` when debugging the triggered function.

Has anyone encountered this? Any ideas/suggestions on this?
Perhaps, this is true? [#23 Functions Framework does not work with the Pub/Sub emulator](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/functions-framework-python/issues/23)

Modules Installed

- functions-framework==2.1.1
- google-cloud-pubsub==2.2.0

python version

- 3.8.8

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll close this post, since the issue is an actual [bug](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/functions-framework-python/issues/23) that was reported last year.
Update: As a workaround until this bug is fixed, I copied the [code](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/functions-framework-python/issues/23#issuecomment-675074119) below locally to `functions_framework/__init__.py` within `view_func` nested function, inside `_event_view_func_wrapper` function.

```
if 'message' in event_data:
    if 'data' not in event_data:
        message = event_data['message']
        event_data['data'] = {
            'data': message.get('data'),
            'attributes': message.get('attributes')
        }
```